# How to store 256 as an integer in a file?

Tags: python

I am learning LZW data compression, and i wanted to store numbers > 255 in a file. The numbers should not be stored as strings otherwise compression will not be effective. However, a binary file only stores numbers <= 255. How can i store numbers greater than 255, such that when i read them back, i get original integer back ?

```
lst = [256]

writefile = open("C:/Users/Dhruv/Desktop/write.bin", "wb")

buffer = bytes(lst)

print(buffer)

writefile.write(buffer)
writefile.close()
readfile = open("C:/Users/Dhruv/Desktop/write.bin", "rb")
bin = readfile.read(1)

print(ord(bin))

readfile.close()
```

Comment: Well, you obviously cannot store it in 1 byte, so you'll need another data format. If you don't write anything else in the file, you could just store the integer in 2 bytes. If you store other integers, you'll need some kind of delimiter inbetween.

Comment: Python will only encode the minimum number of bytes needed to represent an integer, so to store e.g. 4 byte (32 bit) values you will need to manually 'pack' the data with 'empty' bytes. I'm not familiar with Python 3 but it should not be too hard to write a function that does this.

Comment: Ya, just got to know about struct, problem solved, thanks @SimonHibbs